# Compiling a c# application with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, compilation

Currently I'm done with developing a C# desktop application, and I want to install it to the client PC. I've searched how to compile it but I've found different scenarios and I'm lost.

That's what I'm thinking about and please correct me if I'm wrong.

1. Install SQL Server Express edition with .NET framework to the client PC
2. Take the `Bin/Release` executable file

and then I don't what else to do, I even don't know if this is the right steps.
+are there any easier alternatives I mean without installing the SQL Server to the client PC

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a single install on a single machine, or will you install this application on lots of computers?

If it's a single machine you can indeed do it the way you suggest. If you need to install the application on multiple machines I suggest you create an installer for it. Visual Studio includes a project template for this, described here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-file-using-install-shield-le-fr/

You can bundle SQL Express in your setup and install it automatically, but its probably easier for you to just install it manually, and add it as a prerequisite in your installer.

Comment: It is a single install on a single machine So I have to install the .NET framework and SQL express on the client PC , and then what files should I include is the bin/release executable enough?? and what about the connection info can you clear this point for me